# Windows 7 does not go to sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

FIRST of all: Don't mark this question as duplicate. As I saw there are similar questions here but there is no useful answer.

As a developer I have Windows XP, 7 and 10 on one computer.
On Windows XP and 10 there is no problem with sleep or hibernate mode.
I let the computer sleep and all goes off: The LEDs in keyboard and mouse, the harddisk and CPU fan.
The computer seems to be completely off, only the Power LED is blinking. Nothing happens when I use mouse or keyboard while it sleeps. I must press the power button to wake it up. This is perfect.

I want the same behavior on Windows 7, too.
But on Windows 7 I click Sleep or Hibernate and only the monitor goes off.
All the rest stays on and just moving the mouse turns the monitor on again and shows the log on button. It does not want to sleep at all.

I did all described on this page (power plan, disable wake up timers,..)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-7-does-not-go-to-sleep-cb84a4b5-4116-cfb5-a237-5cb287e34320#top
with no success.

I configured all devices so that the command `Powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` returns an empty list now.

Also this page did not help: https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows-7/sleep-problem/

Then I found this page which I found more useful:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/guided-help-get-a-detailed-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-for-your-computer-in-windows-7-3f6ce138-fc04-7648-089a-854bcf332810

which explains how to use the command `powercfg -energy` to diagnose the cause of the problem.
This command generates a file "energy-report.html".

First I got 5 errors of 5 devices which prevent Windows from sleeping. Among them the USB Root hubs which had the Microsoft default drivers. I installed the AMD drivers for the mainboard. After that I had 2 errors less. Only the USB 3.0 drivers are from AMD, the USB 2.0 drivers are still from Microsoft causing problems.

But these 3 are still remainaing:

```
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name     USB Root Hub
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7807
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 18, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_1022&PID_7807
Port Path   

USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name     USB Composite Device
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7807
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 18, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_060B&PID_650A
Port Path   1

USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
The USB device did not enter the Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented if a USB device does not enter the Suspend state when not in use.
Device Name     USB Input Device
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7807
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 18, function 0
Device ID   USB\VID_0458&PID_0188
Port Path   2
```

Below the article there is no help how to solve these problems. The stupid advice from Microsoft is:

> If you encounter power related issues and you do not know how this
> report could help you, you can send the report to a friend to ask for
> help.

Additionally Microsoft is not able to display the names of the devices, but I figured it out manually:

- PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7807 is "Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller".
- USB\VID_1022&PID_7807 is "USB Root Hub"
- USB\VID_060B&PID_650A is "HID Keyboard Device"
- USB\VID_0458&PID_0188 is "HID Compliant Mouse"

All the drivers are from Microsoft.

I have configured both mouse and keyboard not to wake up the computer:

[image: Mouse Keyboard Wake Up Configuration]

So I suppose they should also not prevent sleep mode.

My mouse is a Genius Ammox X1-400 and the keyboard is a Cougar Attack X3 RGB.

I installed what the vendors offer on their homepages, but these are only configuration software (for LED colors and button functionality). After installing all these downloads Control panel still shows the Microsoft HID drivers.

Are all three Microsoft drivers buggy?
And they never fixed that not even in the service pack?
What else can I try to get this working?
How can this be so difficult?

**EDIT:**

1. As r2d3 suggested I disconnected my mouse and keyboard and used another very cheap Genius mouse to start sleep mode while logging the file "energy-report.html". Now it complains about the other mouse and the USB Root Hub USB\VID_1022&PID_7807. Interestingly this root hub appears twice in the HTML file: Once as error: "The USB device did not enter the Suspend state." and once as warning: "The USB device intermittently suspended during the trace." I disabled the driver for "Standard OpenHCD USB Host Controller" which strangely does not affect my USB devices but the error remains.
2. There are no BIOS setting concerning sleep mode of USB devices. And as Windows XP and 10 both go to sleep with the same BIOS settings, the BIOS is surely not the cause.
3. I googled for "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" which is a grayed out checkbox of mouse and keyboard power management. I doubt that this checkbox is the cause of the problem because Windows 10 has exactly the same checkboxes and this one is also disabled and unchecked but Windows 10 goes to sleep without any problem. However I tried what I found here: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/allow-computer-turn-device-save-power This article says to set a registry value `PnPCapabilities` of the mouse driver to zero which should enable this checkbox. But this registry value (which originally did not exist) has no effect on my Windows 7. Then I verified this with my network adapter which also has this checkbox and it is enabled. The checkbox "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" toggles the registry value "PnPCapabilities" of "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" between 0 (checked) and 0x18 (=24) (unchecked) So the article is wrong. This value is the check state of the checkbox and does not affect if the checkbox is enabled or disabled.
4. This page https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/usb-devices-are-not-entering-selective-suspend/bfd1b57b-0536-4f4c-a1dc-ff7ba7b66f15 says to disable "USB selective suspend" but then I even get more errors.

Comment: It is sad to read such a unproductive comment! You sound like a Microsoft sales representative.

Virtual PCs might emulate USB but not other hardware that is used to control machines in an industrial setting p.e. What about RS232? What about GPIB? There are lots of legacy installations around. And before mentioning any "security" arguments - they are isolated from the internet.

Have a look at programs that are available cross-platform and cover even DOS platforms such as Testdisk, p.e.

Comment: r2d3: Thanks for your comment. Using virtual machines is really a stupid advice. I hate them because they are very slow and unstable and consume a lot of CPU and RAM. I had a Linux on a virtual machine and it was a nightmare to work with it and finally some day suddenly it did boot with an error and I could not use it anymore.

Comment: @Gantendo Sometimes, I wish "modern" web developers would use browsers from 5 years ago. Maybe if they did they would actually make compatible websites that actually works, instead of throwing a bunch of ECMAScript bleeding edge JS errors or downright crashing. If an application works on XP, it'll probably work on any version of Windows NT, pretty much

Comment: For web development this is true. But for XP only partly. There were many new obstacles coming up in Vista which broke software written for XP, like elevation, Data Execution Prevention, required permission to write to protected registry and file system areas, and other security features. On XP there was no security at all. You logged in as admin and could do whatever you liked on the computer. On Vista this became far more complicated.

Comment: Gotta love the circlejerk of dinosaurs who are unable to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is incredible, but true: After several months I found a solution by chance.

I wanted to free space on my harddisk and thought that I do not need 2 Gigabyte occupied by C:\Hiberfil.sys

I turned hibernation off and the side effect was that my computer goes to sleep now! Yeah!

Open a command prompt as administrator and enter:

```
powercfg /hibernate off
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out if checking "allow this device to wake the computer" enables the line above to be checked.

Your Windows settings might interfere with a power-related BIOS setting.

Remove your current mouse and keyboard and just connect another mouse or keyboard trying to exclude possible causes of shutdown denial.

**added 1.5.2022 23:54 MESZ:**

I fear it may be your USB HUB. Just starting with another keyboard won't work either, but you can try it out if you have another different one.

Here is another proposal:
If you have a free PCIExpress left over, install any simple
Renesas uPD720202 PCIExpress card.

As far as I remember, there is a power management switch in the properties of this device.

Retry after installation.

Comment: I modified my answer in response to your findings.

Comment: You are too fast. I had to edit it again due to new findings. The Usb Hub works on XP and 10. There is surely no hardware problem. I use 8 USB ports on the mainboard. These PciExpress cards have far less ports. Disabling them all and replacing them with PCI ports is no option. It slowly becomes clear to me that what I found are multiple bugs in the Microsoft's Windows 7 USB drivers. I see no way to solve this.

Comment: To eliminate interference. ••• Turn off the PC and pull all external usb attached items. ••• Turn the PC back on and open up msconfig. ••• Select the services tab, and check the box to hide all MS services. ••• Uncheck all non-MS services. ••• Go to the Start tab and uncheck all non MS startup items. ••• Reboot clean and see if your PC hibernates and sleeps as you desire it to. ••• If it does, then one-by-one, reinstall (mscomfig/recheck check boxes) each 3rd party service (and reboot each time) until you find the culprit, and then check out its settings.

Comment: These tests are not necessary. As I already wrote the culprit is the driver of the USB root hub, which I cannot remove. I cannot even "pull all external USB devices" as you write. This would result in staying without mouse and keyboard. And when I screw up the USB drivers I cannot even restore the drivers without keyboard. So  this is a VERY bad idea! Apart it is useless to know which device is the culprit if there is no bug-free driver from Microsoft which works correctly. I already have the latest driver versions.